# How can I use react-datepicker in the ReScript app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reason, rescript

I`m trying to use an external library such as react-datepicker.

My code and usage:

```
module DatePicker = {
  @react.component @module("react-datepicker")
  external make: () => React.element = "default";
}

@react.component
let make = () => {
  <DatePicker />
}
```

However, I`ve got an error:

**Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
Check the render method of ...**

P.S.:
I tried a solution from this answer [Can't create ReasonML bindings for react-contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538802/cant-create-reasonml-bindings-for-react-contenteditable) but it doesn't help me with an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@scope decorator is a solution**

```
module Dp = {
  @react.component @module("react-datepicker") @scope("default")
  external make: () => React.element = "default";
}

@react.component
let make = () => {
  <Dp />
}
```

https://forum.rescript-lang.org/t/help-with-binding-currying/1540/11?u=grigoryev